How do I ensure sequential document numbering using EF Core with a SQL database?
I have a simple application that must assign a sequential number without gaps or duplicates to each Document that is created i.e. 1, 2, 3 etc. A different document type will have a different numering sequence.
DocumentTypes is a database table which stores the different types of documents e.g. Book, Recipe, WhitePaper
Documents is a database table which stores the document info including its sequential ID
The database relationship is one DocumentType can have many Documents but each Document will have only one DocumentType
If DocumentType.LastNumber holds the last number assigned for a particular document type, my plan was:
// create a transaction to lock the DocumentType row being assigned so no duplicates
var transaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable);

// get the appropriate document type from the db
var documentType = dbContext.DocumentTypes.Single(t => t.Id == 1);

// increment the last document number
documentType.LastNumber++;    

// create the new document with the new number
documentType.Documents.Add(new Document{
    Id = documentType.LastNumber,
    ...
});

dbContext.SaveChanges();

// commit the transaction and release the db lock
transaction.Commit();

However, what Im finding is that I get duplicate numbers for a given document type (when I call this method asynchronously via API)
I suspect I have misunderstood how database transactions and IsolationLevel.Serializable work. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

On a side note: I don't know your jurisdiction, but it's a myth in most jurisdictions that invoice numbers need to not have gaps or be in order, just that they are unique.

Which DBMS is this, is it SQL Server?

@Charlieface it is indeed SQL server. This particular case isnt for invoice numbers, though I appreciate your note ;)

Assuming you are using SQL Server, you need to add a UPDLOCK hint, to tell the server that the row is going to be modified. You might as well be explicit about SERIALIZABLE as well.
var documentType = dbContext
    .DocumentTypes.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM dbo.DocumentType WITH (SERIALIZABLE, UPDLOCK)")
    .Single(t => t.Id == 1);

Note that transaction needs a using to dispose it correctly.

Very helpful, thanks. Given that a row lock would be sufficient (I dont want to block any other concurrent DocumentType updates) I should be able to omit the SERIALIZABLE hint, which then because of the UPDLOCK would default to a row lock (without the need for the ROWLOCK hint) correct?

Also, do I still need to specify the IsolationLevel in BeginTransaction() given the UPDLOCK hint is specified when I read the DocumentType from the db anyway?

You are getting all your hints mixed up. SERIALIZABLE is the same as IsolationLevel.Serializable although the latter specifies it for all tables rather than just one. UPDLOCK turns a S-lock into a U-lock (which means it blocks other U-locks, which S-locks do not), but does not affect lock escalation (the size of the lock). ROWLOCK is enitrely separate, and forces the lock to not be escalated to page or table locks, this is anyway unnecessary if Id is unique, as it would never be escalated anyway.

if it were me,
I would not have the no gap number thing... just my preference.
However, given your desire, I would create a trigger on the document table to populate the incrementing number using a sequence.

It gets complicated. The governing authority requires the no-gaps AND requires a signature for the document which includes the document number in it. I could save to db first, wait for the trigger to insert the number, pull the document from db again and then sign... but Im intrigued as to why the db transaction doesnt do what I expected.
